# Galois Covering of $P^1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, galois-theory, covering-spaces

I read this somewhere, I just want to confirm the authenticity.

If we have Galois covering $$X\longrightarrow P^{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}$$ defined over rationals which is cyclic. I mean the Galois Group associated to the covering is cyclic group. 
Then X can not be $P^{1}_\mathbb{Q}$

My first question is is this result true,

And if yes, Can we find some curve of higher genus where quotient is $P^{1}_\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: I'm confused any Galois covering is of the form $\mathbb{P}^1_L\to\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Q}$ for $L/\mathbb{Q}$ a Galois extension.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Can you mention the reference, I don't know about any such result.